# Create variable with apostrophe and double quote PHP

Tags: php, variables

How to create variable when you have massive data with ' and " in it whitout addslashes.

```
 <?
 // Create variable with single and double quote.

 s = ' massive data with """ and '''' inside.... ';

 ?>
```

I try

```
 addslashes(s) = ' massive data in with """ and '''' inside.... ';
```

but i think i miss something. I cant change manually every apostrophe because its massive.

Thanks you !

Comment: You can escape them by using backward slash

Comment: Thanks you sir but what if I have massive data with thousand of single and double quote

Comment: You can now use pregmatch or str replace . Or get char-code and replace with. New one. (Expect 1st and last one)

Comment: After testing a lot of things this weork perfecly for me so far $variable = file_get_content('./mymassivedatafullofcrap.txt'); // then i easily manipulate the data with str_replace and whatever thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the backslash escape character:

```
$string = ' massive data in with """ and \'\'\'\' inside....';
```

Simply use a `\` before any character you wish to be interpreted as part of a string.

I've created an 3v4l demonstrating the above code **[here](https://3v4l.org/ngYqs)**.

Alertnatively, if you have a large text string that contains **both** single quotes and double quotes, you can use a **[heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)** to avoid needing to escape individual characters:

```
$str = <<<EOD
' massive data with """ and '''' inside.... ';
EOD;
echo $str;
```

I've created another 3v4l example of this **[here](https://3v4l.org/DX9NO)**.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: THanks but the data is massive i have thousand of single and double quote. What do i do in this situation thanks you sir !

Comment: I've updated my answer to cover an alternative approach, while will allow you to use multiple double and single quotes without needing to escape them individually :)

Comment: Thanks you very much sir !

Comment: I had so much data it was not working very well so I try $variable = file_get_content(./mymassivedata.txt);  Thanks you very much !